# Typescript - Loop through an array backwards with noUncheckedIndexedAccess enabled

Tags: arrays, typescript

What is the best way to loop through an array backwards in TypeScript, with `strict` and `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` options enabled? The most classic approach no longer works well in this config:

```
function doSomething(i: number): void {
  ...
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3];
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  doSomething(arr[i]);
}
```

It fails with a compilation error:

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: I'd just assert that the value exists with `!`, as long as you aren't doing anything strange like mutating the array you're iterating over inside the function

Comment: Thanks, sounds like a reasonable solution. Do you want to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`noUncheckedIndexedAccess` is [primarily useful for objects](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess), and for arrays if the index you're looking up might be more than the length of the array.

If you can be absolutely certain that the value exists at the index specified - such as with dead-simple code like this (assuming you don't mutate the array inside the function) - then simply assert that the value exists before passing it around:

```
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
  doSomething(arr[i]!);
}
```

Another option would be to reverse the array, then iterate over it, which is a bit more computationally expensive, but easier to make sense of at a glance.

```
arr.reverse().forEach(doSomething);
```

```
// no mutation:
[...arr].reverse().forEach(doSomething);
```

```
// no mutation:
for (const item of [...arr].reverse()) {
    doSomething(item);
}
```

Those last three are what I'd prefer over a `for` loop when feasible.

Comment: Thanks! I personally generally prefer the first solution for computation cost. I don't like to copy arrays when not necessary. I would generally avoid the second option either because it would cause surprise if `arr` is used somewhere else after this code.

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't do it as anyone else

```
arr.map(dosonething);
```

Buy if you still want to do it as you Is add an if

```
if (art[I]!==undefined){
dosonething(art[I]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't think your first code snippet meets the "backwards" part of the question. Your second code snippet does, but it looks a bit redundant, as it really can never be undefined. I personally prefer [the other answer by CertainPerformance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69861146/4339963) for conciseness.